# How to export mlab database to meteor application

Tags: meteor, mlab

I have created a mlab database. But I am unable to export it to meteor application.Everytime I try to connect, it throws an error "mongoError: failed to connect to server [ds035693.mlab.com:35693] on first connect".Command I am using is

`"export MONGO_URL= mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds035693.mlab.com:35693/abcd"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you don't need " " around your export. just put this in your terminal

```
export MONGO_URL= mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds035693.mlab.com:35693/abcd
```

replace with your id and password.

and `console.log(process.env);` in your startup function to check if MONGO_URL is set or not.
if this is set. this may be your network issue.

you may be forgot to `add database user` in `user` tab for your collection in mlab.

hope this will help

Comment: console.log(process.env) doesn't output anything.Few seconds after I run command error shows up .

Comment: @dpatnaik console.log(process.env) should be in Meteor.startup() in server side.

Comment: Yes, I have written on server side

Comment: I am not able to connect using mongo shell too.

Comment: mongo shell will not work if we export our MONGO_URL to mlab. can you show your code somehow.

Comment: i use same export MONGO_URL daily. it works for me. make sure you have added user to your mlab collection with all permissions

Comment: I am connecting to mongo shell via follwing command mongo ds035693.mlab.com:35693/abcd -u xxxx -p yyyyyy

Comment: well i never tried this command. have you added user to your collection in mlab ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a database user in mLab, with an id and password.

Then your `MONGO_URL` should like:

`mongodb://<id>:<password>@ds035693.mlab.com:35693/abcd`

Note that it is NOT your account credentials.

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried mongodb://<id>:<password>@ds035693.mlab.com:35693/abcd, but still does not doesn't work.

Comment: Are you replacing `<id>` and `<password>` by what you have set for your DB user?

Comment: Then you need to share much more details about your setup, how you start meteor, and the error(s) you get, should you need any further help.